# SSRS: When using "Select all" for a parameter, show totals instead of individual records

Tags: sql-server, reporting-services

We have several hierarchies that we wish to use as parameters in our Reporting Services environment.

I.e.

```
**SalesRegion** -- **Country**
Americas -- Canada
Americas -- United States
APAC -- Australia
APAC -- Japan
EMEA -- Germany
EMEA -- United Kingdom
```

We implemented parameters allowing our users to pick one or multiple regions (along with a "Select All" option) for `SalesRegions`, and `Country`. The report then will show specific sales data based on the user's selection, as well as a bunch of graphs (cause managers like graphs).

The typical scenario would be a regional manager picks his or her region, and then some focus countries. However, we also have top level management using the same report, and they're more interested in the overall overview, and thus typically would pick the "Select all" option for both `SalesRegion` and `Country`.

Unfortunately, we have the query set in using a `WHERE` clause using `IN` for both `SalesRegion` and `Country`, and thus the report happily spits out every country that ever made a sale, leading to a massive barf of data and graphs speckled with lines.

Would it somehow be possible to show aggregated numbers in the case a user picked `Select all` as a parameter? I'm not against using a second dataset containing all the aggregated numbers, but wouldn't know how to assign that as the basis for reports on the condition that "Select all" was picked.

Comment: Did you provide multiple select or single select parameter ?

Comment: Would it be sensible to have another (boolean) parameter called something like "just show me aggregates" that can be checked to change the display? I don't know the details of the report, but the groupings could include a reference to this new parameter to choose how to sum the data? This might be easier than triggering the change on whether all options are selected, and could be more flexible for the user.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have essentially three ways of achieving this:

- Add an explicit parameter option for "All" (i.e. not the "Select All" option) and use that in your dataset to return a different result.
- Determine if the user selected all possible values in the query.
- Do the grouping in your report.

**Explicit Parameter Option**

Assume your dataset query looks like

```
select sum(salesAmt) as TotalSales, Country, SalesRegion
WHERE Country IN ISNULL(@Country, Country) AND SalesRegion IN ISNULL(@SalesRegion, SalesRegion)
GROUP BY Country, SalesRegion
```

And your SalesRegion (and Country) parameter queries look like

```
select Country as Label, Country as Value
From Country
Union
select 'All' as Label, NULL as value
```

You can switch your dataset to something like

```
    select 
    sum(salesAmt) as TotalSales, 
    CASE WHEN @Country IS NULL THEN 'All' else Country end as Country, 
    CASE WHEN @SalesRegion IS NULL then 'All' else SalesRegion end as SalesRegion
    WHERE Country = ISNULL(@Country, Country) 
AND SalesRegion = ISNULL(@SalesRegion, SalesRegion)
    GROUP BY CASE WHEN @Country IS NULL then 'All' else Country end, 
    CASE WHEN @SalesRegion IS NULL then 'All' else SalesRegion end
```

Now if the user selects the explicit "All" option for countries and sales region, this returns a single total for all. If they select one region but All for countries, they get the total for that region

The problem, of course, is you've lost your granularity - they get All and that's that. And of course user training.

**Query Hack**

In your dataset, add this:

```
declare @userSelectedAllContries tinyint;
select @userSelectedAllCountries = 
    case when 
     ( select count(distinct Country) from DataSet)  =
    ( select count(distinct Country) from Dataset where Country in (@Country) ) 
    then 1 else 0 end;
```

If the user hit Select All on the multi-value parameter, this will return a 1 instead of a 0, and you can use it in your query to aggregate and return a different set of data.

**Report Grouping**

This is essentially an extension of method #2 from above. Rather than return a different dataset, simply append this value as a new column to your dataset (even better, rather than return 1 or 0, return 'All' if it's 1 and the Country / SalesRegion value if it's 0.) Then in your report, use this new column as a parent group.

So if the user selects all sales regions, by default group the data using this new column (which will be set to "All" for all rows in the dataset), and then still allows them to expand this down to the individual level if they so desire.